# Can the controller code generation template be changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, code-generation

In Visual Studio when you add a new controller to your MVC application some macro creates a file with methods like:

```
//
// GET: /Thing/Details/5

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

I want my methods to look like:

```
/// <example>GET: /Thing/Details/XXX...</example>
public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
{
    return View(Repository.GetItem<Thing, Guid>(id, "Id"));
}
```

The main differences are standard notation for the comments with the two redundant lines removed and I use unique identifiers rather than integers for my id's. If possible, I'd like the code to pass my Model to the view to also be generated.

Is there a built in mechanism that will let me control the code template that is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think David Hayden has a solution for you here. [Blog Post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2009/01/29/overriding-global-t4-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-project-with-per-project-templates.aspx)